# Primes $p$ and $q$ with $(2016/p)=(2016/q)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> i. Let $p,q\geq11$ be prime with $p\equiv q\pmod{56}$. Prove that
> $$
>  \left(\frac{2016}p\right)=\left(\frac{2016}{q}\right).
>  $$
> ii. Find six progressions $\pmod{56}$ such that whenever $P\geq11$ is a prime in these progressions then $(2016\mid P)=1$.

I am able to solve (i), but I am wondering if there is a better method than the one I used.

**What I've done:** First I see that
$$
\begin{align*}\left(\frac{2016}p\right)&=\left(\frac{2^5}p\right)\left(\frac{3^2}p\right)\left(\frac{7}p\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2^2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{2^2}p\right)\left(\frac{3^2}p\right)\left(\frac{7}p\right).
\end{align*}
$$
Since $p\geq11$ it is certain that $2^2$ and $3^2$ are quadratic residues $\pmod p$. So the quantity above is $(2016\mid p)=(2\mid p)(7\mid p)$. Same thing for $q$: $(2016\mid q)=(2\mid q)(7\mid q)$.

Since $p\equiv q\pmod{56}$, We know that $p\equiv q\pmod8$ and $p\equiv q\pmod4$. Since $p\equiv q\pmod8$ we know $(2\mid p)=(2\mid q)$. Since $p\equiv q\pmod4$ we know $(7\mid p)=(7\mid q)$. Therefore $(2016\mid p)=(2016\mid q)$.

**My question:** Is there a better way to do part (i)? I did not seem to fully utilize the fact that $p\equiv q\pmod{56}$, which leads me to believe there might be a better way to do this problem. I see that $2016=56\times36$, but I do not know how to use this.

Any hints on (i) or (ii) would be appreciated.

Comment: Your answer to part (i) looks great, other than writing (mod 4) twice when you meant (mod 7). (Indeed the second deduction requires both (mod 4) and (mod 7).) As for (ii), which progressions (mod 8) are quadratic residues? Which progressions (mod 7) are quadratic residues? How can these progressions be combined to make progressions (mod 56)?

Comment: Why do you have multiple factors of p in the denominator? Are those fractions or something else?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, for part (i) I missed the fact that p=q (mod 7) was necessary for saying (7/p)=(7/q). And thank you for the hint for part (ii). I know that 2 is a quadratic residue for primes in the progressions 1 and -1 (mod 8), as well as that 7 is a quadratic residue for primes in 1, 2, 4 (mod 7). Combining those congruences with the chinese remainder theorem I get 6 equivalences (mod 56).